# Does a Brahma jnani also need deeksha in order to make a mantra to work?

Tags: mantras, brahma, guru, enlightenment, yantra

if i want to use mantra to work i need to get deeksha from guru. What i am asking is Like that if brahma nani want to use mantra to work whether he also need to get deeksha from guru or not.

Comment: As per advaita, brahma-jnAni attains identity with **nirguNa brahman and not with saguNa brahman (Ishwara)**. In the state of nirguNa brahman, there are no upAdhis or limiting adjuncts like omniscience, omnipotence, etc., which Ishwara would have (though Ishwara is also a jnAni). Thus, a jnAni is not omnipotent in this world nor is he/she necessarily expected to have any special powers. He/she may have powers due to other reasons, but not due to brahma jnAna. So yes, jnAni would also need deeksha in order to make a mantra work.

Comment: if i want to use mantra to work i need to get deeksha from guru. What i am asking is Like that if brahma nani want to use mantra to work whether he also need to get deeksha from guru or not.

Answer (score 1):

Deeksha may be or may not be necessary for attaining Brahma Jnana or SELF REALISATION.  It depends on the prArabdha of the individual concerned.

1) Ramakrishna "Gadadhar" Chattopadhyay later known as ***Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa*** [had Gurus for initiating him into various methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna#Formative_religious_practices_and_teachers) of worship of the Almighty.

- Bhairavi Brahmani initiated Ramakrishna into Tantra,
- Ramakrishna took up the practise of vātsalya bhāva under a Vaishnava guru Jatadhari
- Advaita Vedantist and Digambara monk Tota Puri initiated Ramakrishna into sannyasa and non-dual meditation

2) [Sri Ramana Maharshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramana_Maharshi) or [Sri Anandmayi Ma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anandamayi_Ma) had no formal initiation from any Guru

---

In respect of Sri Anandamayi Ma the following was how [she got initiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anandamayi_Ma#Early_life).

> Anandamayi was born Nirmala Sundari Devi on 30 April 1896.
>
> On the full moon night of August 1922, at midnight,
>   twenty-six-year-old Nirmala enacted ***her own spiritual
>   initiation***. She explained that the ceremony and its rites were
>   being revealed to her spontaneously as and when they were called for.
>
> Although uneducated on the matter, the complex rites corresponded to
>   those of traditional, ancient Hinduism, including the offerings of
>   flowers, the mystical diagrams (yantras) and the fire ceremony
>   (yagna).
>
> She later stated, "***As the master (guru) I revealed the mantra; as
>   the disciple (shishya) I accepted it and started to recite it***."

[image]